# Sencha Touch height difference between dev and production builds

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

We have a web application, built originally on Sencha Touch 2.1. We have recently been working on upgrading to Sencha Touch 2.3. The app has a bottom docked tab bar. When we view the development version on the app on an iPad (iPad 2 and 3) everything works correctly.

When we build a production release and view it, the bottom bar is no longer visible. We have noticed that the body has a different height version when using the dev vs the production build.

We can't seem to nail down why it's different but the difference is what is causing the bar to not be visible.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sencha production builds, the development logging, deprecation warnings, and synchronous asset loading is disabled.

This means:

1. If you're using a deprecated function or property,  will not see deprecations warnings, and the function will not work
2. If you are using a component that you did not declare in your app.js, or properly add as a required component, it will not be compiled into the final app.

Check your development build's console log for deprecation warnings, and synchronously loading warnings.

Comment: I'm going mark your answer as your preety close. We found some odd JS code burried in an external JS file we pull in that was modifying the viewport meta tag setting width=980. I believe that the JS was executing in a different order due to the optimizations you mentioned when in production build